# Installing python 3.6 on mac along with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew

Want to install python 3.6 on mac along with pip.

brew install python - installs python 3.7 and pip will be installed along with that.

Online docs instructs installing python3.6 using below command
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb

But this doesn't install pip along with it, also python3 get-pip.py fails with below SSL cert error.

```
python3 get-pip.py
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
```

May I know right way of installing python 3.6 on Mac along with correct pip ?

Comment: Have you now installed both python3.7 and python3.6 on your system?

Comment: What does `python3 -V` give you?

Comment: python3 -V
Python 3.6.5

Comment: Can you test whether a `pip` module got installed together with Python 3.6? Try `python -m pip` and see whether you get an error, or the help output for pip.

Comment: If `python3` is 3.6 then you should at least be able to do `python3 -m pip install <whatever>` to get the 3.6 `pip`.

Comment: Any pip operation is giving below error

pip install -U pip==20.0.2
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/

Answer (score 1):

I could install python 3.6 and pip along with it by downloading and installing brew pkg from,

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/

Thanks for help.